# F#'s `netcore` class library shared by both `netframework` and `netcore` projects written in plain C#?

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-assembly

So here we go: there are a lot of `Net Framework` projects, most of them are `>= 4.7`, written in pure C#. And there are necessities to introduce new assemblies, written in F# for no matter what purposes, and `netcore` is desired. Is there any way to make new stuff referencable by `netframework` projects?

Comment: You can make libraries targeting .net standard, which is usable by framework and net core projects - is that what you're after?

Comment: @ReedCopsey does it limit me dramatically?

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov depends what features you need; some areas will work without change in netstandard - some will need additional nuget package refs for additional pieces - and some won't work at all! although frankly, I'd suggest that making it usable from .NET Framework is a non-goal at this point: https://blog.marcgravell.com/2020/01/net-core-net-5-exodus-of-net-framework.html

Comment: You might get some backgrounds from https://blog.lextudio.com/which-class-library-project-to-go-in-visual-studio-2015-2017-a48710cf3dff